# How to paginate listview in jQuery-Mobile?

Tags: listview, cross-browser, pagination, jquery-mobile

I will like to display a long list in jQuery-Mobile, but I will like to split the list into multiple pages with previous - next buttons similar to gmail applications. The number of items per page will depend on the page height and will be different.

Even the answer on how to decide number of elements based on screen height will help solve the problem as creations of buttons and pages though not easy, is possible.

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: I think you can use jquery mobile list view with searching facility

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the pagination to work for the user, so it should be done server-side. Paginating the content that was already downloaded doesn't make much sense (unless you only care for a feeling)

1. Before showing the list - get the optimum length for a single page
2. Put it (with a bit of js) in the URL as a parameter
3. Paginate with this setting like in the old times

To determine the number:
Make the button that lets user go to the list a 1 element listview.
Get the window height, substract height of heder and footer, divide by the 1 element height and put as a parameter to the link.

done

Comment: "Paginating the content that was already downloaded doesn't make much sense" a page with 100+ items might be fast to download but won't be as easy to navigate. Breaking it up into separate pages might be worth it for certain cases. I think doing this client-side definitely has its uses.

Comment: The whole idea of pagination is built on the purpose of splitting content for speed and ease of delivery. If it wast fast to download and display 100+ records you would simply let the user scroll through them.

Comment: I agree with Jordan Reiter, sometimes it does make sense. I my case I am needing this functionality because my application is available offline, therefore server side is not an option. And in my case I have well over 1000 items, so not user friendly to navigate without pagination.